# javascript replace 2 characters

Tags: javascript

i would like to ask, how to replace char "(" and ")" with ""

it is because i can only replace either ( or ) with "" instead of both

how to achieve the goal??

that is

original: (abc, def)

modified:  abc, def

thanks

my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str="(abc, def)";
document.write(str.replace("(",""));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a regexp, and the **g** for global replacements:

```
var str="(abc, def)";
document.write(str.replace(/[()]/g,''));
```

For reference: http://javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex, or

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str="(abc, def)";
document.write(str.replace("(","").replace(")",""));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This method is actually safe and cleaner because chaining of replace() works just fine even if the element given to be replaced is not actually existing in the string. (even if "(" or ")" doesn't exist in the string)

Answer (score 2):

If the parentheses will be the first and last characters, you could avoid a regular expression by [using `.substring()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nRh3C/

```
var string =  "(abc, def)";

alert( string.substring(1, string.length-1) );
```

or [using `.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nRh3C/1/

```
var string =  "(abc, def)";

alert( string.substr(1, string.length -2) );
```

Answer (score 1):

use `str.replace(/\(/g,'').replace(/\)/g,'');`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version using a single regexp is `str.replace(/\(|\)/g,"");`